# Missing top padding on question pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The top padding of the content area has vanished in Chrome 15, causing the text to be stuck up against the border separating it from the title.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed now; see [Padding at the top of question bodies has gone missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing).